# Page renders incorrectly on pre kitkat device [WebView]

Tags: android, css, webview, ionic-framework

I have created this page to be rendered on mobile webivew:

http://www.madhur.co.in/jobform/

The source is here:
https://github.com/madhur/jobform

It works on fine devices, except pre kitkat devices where the bottom two slider do not render full width. I am using this simple angular component for the slider

https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider

Any ideas what could be wrong with such a simple page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through your code and realized that I too faced a similar issue in the past. Then the culprit was `-flex-box`.

ionic.css uses `flex`. Android 4.3 version had partial support for flexbox. It is completely supported from Android 4.4 onward. [See this.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Have a look at this [discussion](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/998) as well.

Solution here could be to overwrite CSS properties. Eg.: replacing `display: flex / inline-flex` with `display: block` or `display: inline`

More generic solution could be to use [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) webview in the project. This makes your Cordova / Ionic application use the Crosswalk WebView instead of the System WebView. 
This webview plugin would help in eliminating device specific or webview specific issues as app would use the same webview across all the devices.

You can add iionic plugin as follows:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Cool ... That did it :)